# PostgreSQL select optimization

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

Can you please explain, how I can optimize select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM calls WHERE id_temp % 5 = 0 LIMIT 300000
```

This select is working on table with 50 millions of records.

Thanks a lot and have a nice day.

Comment: Create an index on `id_temp`. this will improve the performance.

Comment: i'm trying to make it now.
I'll update, as soon as I'll finish and try.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info and the asking better questions section of  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info. In particular, Pg version, explain analyze?

Comment: Unlikely that an index is going to help, due to low selectivity.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `id_temp` has not some highly skewed (in favour of your query) distribution, I don't see any way of optimizing this query.

You want 300K rows and the chances of a row matching the condition is about 1/5 (under the non-skewed assumption) so it is going to read about 1.5 million rows from the table until it find 300K matches.

Even if you have an index on `id_temp` and the 300K matches are found faster, the 300K rows have to still be read from the table (as you have `SELECT *`) and since they are going to be interleaved with the non-matching rows, it is still going to read about the same number of disk pages as without the index.

I think your best chances - besides improving disk I/O performance - are if you have the table partitioned using the `id_temp % 5` expression in some way - but I'll leave this to Postgres experts. Perhaps some other magic will work better.

Another idea is an index with the `id_temp % 5` expression as first column but this is essentially duplicating the whole 50M rows table:

```
CREATE INDEX id_temp_modulo_5_idx 
   ON calls 
   ( (id_temp % 5), id_temp, --- all the other columns as well --- );
```

or a partial index if you only need the `= 0` condition and never going to need `=1` (or 2, 3,4). This will save about 80% space compared to the above one:

```
CREATE INDEX id_temp_modulo_5_equals_0_idx 
    ON calls 
    ( (id_temp % 5), id_temp, --- all the other columns as well --- )
WHERE
    (id_temp % 5 = 0) ;
```